# How to send array of data to mongodb using reactjs components?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I need to send set of data to an array in mongodb after submitting a form.

Comment: you might want to refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42890055/insert-mongodb-document-with-react-js

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert MongoDB document with React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42890055/insert-mongodb-document-with-react-js)